# Deriving Lorentz transformation - Serway

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames

in Serway, the derivation of [Lorentz transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation) started from these two equations
$$x′=\gamma(x−ut),$$
$$x=\gamma(x′+ut′).$$

The book derived the first equation and then deduced the second. Is there a proof that if the first is right then the second is also right?

To be specific I don't understand:

1. How $t$ was converted to $t′$ in the second equation.
2. Why the position of $\gamma$ didn't change in the second equation.

Note: I understand the first equation well but I don't understand how to reach the second from the first.

Comment: The symbol outside the parenthesis as not $y$ (`y`), but $\gamma$ (`\gamma`) and it is not a position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The principle of relativity states the laws of physics should be the same in any reference frame. This means that for any general equation that can be written down in one reference frame can be written down in any other.

Now in the standard set up for the lorentz transformations we have one frame $S$ with coordinates $(t,x,y,z)$ and another frame $S^\prime$ with coordinates $(t^\prime,x^\prime,y^\prime,z^\prime)$ moving at a velocity $u$ relative to the unprimed frame. We can find the coordinates of an event in $s^\prime$ from its coordinates in $S$ using the first equation \begin{equation}x^\prime = \gamma(x-ut)\end{equation} However we can also say that the $S$ frame is moving at a velocity $-u$ relative to the primed frame, and the same laws of physics must apply, so we can write down the same law for transforming from frame $S^\prime$ to frame $S$ by simply substituting $t\rightarrow t^\prime$, $x\rightarrow x^\prime$, $x^\prime\rightarrow x$ and $u \rightarrow -u$ (since $\gamma$ only depends on the magnitude of $u$ it is unchanged) This leads to the second equation \begin{equation}x = \gamma(x^\prime+ut^\prime)\end{equation}

Comment: Your name is quite appropriate in answering this question ;)

Comment: so we wrote it down as it is one of the postulates of relativity and then deduced Lorentz transformation from this postulates ??

Comment: We can derive the Lorentz transformations from the postulates of relativity. Once we have done that, however, the postulates of relativity are still true and can still be used to deduce further results. I particular since we used the fact that the laws of physics are the same in any reference frame to derive the the Lorentz transformations, it must certainly be true that the Lorentz transforms are the correct transformation laws regardless of which frame we are in. So the equation must be the same, only the relative velocity is in the other direction, i.e. it has the opposite sign.